# How to bind data to a dropdownlist based on another dropdownlist value both are in gridview only

Tags: c#

I just want to take the rates of a product from db based on selected product size and product table.
product table name, rate and size are bounded to dropdownlist inside gridview.
heres my grid view

```
        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="drptype" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem>Marbles</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Granites</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Tiles</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Size">

        <ItemTemplate>

          <asp:DropDownList ID="drpsize" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="granites" DataTextField="size" DataValueField="size">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quality">

        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpquality" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="tiles" DataTextField="quality" DataValueField="quality">
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">

        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtquantity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">

        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtrate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">

        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Label ID="lbltotal" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        </ItemTemplate>

        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />

        <FooterTemplate>

         <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click"/>

        </FooterTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
```

my code

private void SetInitialRow()
    {

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    DataRow dr = null;

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column5", typeof(string)));

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column6", typeof(string)));

    dr = dt.NewRow();

    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;

    dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;

    dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;

    dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;

    dr["Column4"] = string.Empty;

    dr["Column5"] = string.Empty;

    dr["Column6"] = string.Empty;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //dr = dt.NewRow();



    //Store the DataTable in ViewState

    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;



    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;

    Gridview1.DataBind();

}
private void AddNewRowToGrid()
{

    int rowIndex = 0;



    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {

        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];

        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                //extract the TextBox values

                DropDownList  box1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("drptype");

                DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("drpsize");

                DropDownList box3 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("drpquality");

                TextBox box4 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtquantity");

                TextBox box5 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtrate");

                Label box6 = (Label)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("lbltotal");

                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;



                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column4"] = box4.Text;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column5"] = box5.Text;

                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column6"] = box6.Text;



                rowIndex++;

            }

            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);

            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;



            Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;

            Gridview1.DataBind();

        }

    }

    else
    {

        Response.Write("ViewState is null");

    }



    //Set Previous Data on Postbacks

    SetPreviousData();

}
private void SetPreviousData()
{

    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DropDownList box1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("drptype");

                DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("drpsize");

                DropDownList box3 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("drpquality");

                TextBox box4 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtquantity");

                TextBox box5 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtrate");

                Label box6 = (Label)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("lbltotal");



                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();

                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();

                box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();

                box5.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column5"].ToString();

                box6.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column6"].ToString();

                rowIndex++;

            }

        }

    }



}
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    AddNewRowToGrid();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is to use a cascading dropdownlist from jquery. What happens on the change of first dropdownlist item you need to call your codebehind and get value for the second one. Now since you are doing web form it wont be straightforward to call a code behind method from jquery. You need to decorate method to retrieve dropdownlist values with [WebMethod] attribute. Hope this helps